Dividing 2 metrics, one metric is missing a label, set this label to 0 instead of ignoring it
I'm trying to get the success rate of a metric doing:
gateway_fetch_success_count / gateway_fetch_count

gateway_fetch_count has data:
{gateway_url="https://server1.com"} 10
{gateway_url="https://server2.com"} 10

gateway_fetch_success_count has data
{gateway_url="https://server1.com"} 5

I want my graph to include {gateway_url="https://server2.com"} with 0% success rate. But it is not returned at all in the data.
From what I understand counters should not be initiated to 0, and I should use a query like:
(gateway_fetch_success_count or vector(0)) / on(gateway_url) group_left gateway_comment_fetch_count

But this still doesn't seem to display {gateway_url="https://server2.com"} with 0% success rate.

Use gateway_fetch_success_count / gateway_fetch_count or gateway_fetch_count * 0 instead. Vector(0) will not work for you because of how vector matching works in Prometheus.
